# Two GRUB menus from Hyper-V

Tags: grub-efi, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu running on Hyper-V on Windows 10

I created the VM using the HYPER-V Quick Create and selected the Ubuntu 19.04

[image]

I have found that the grub boot menu does not get updated when i edited the /etc/default/grub file and run update-grub

So I executed install-grub  and I now when I execute shutdown -r I get two Grub menus - the first one being the one I am updating with the update-grub command

If I power the machine off and then power it on using the Hyper V - I only get the second grub menu

This is what Gparted shows - the only partition bootable is the UEFI one
[image]

If i do

> apt-get upgrade

Grub does upgrade to a new version and identifies two drives to install on
[image]

I did not select either and it still has the two menus

Since Hyper V is showing the second menu - how do I get rid of the first menu and then change my configuration so update-grub updates the correct menu?

It also occurs using the 18.04.03 LTS image upgraded to the latest version